# net::ERR_ABORTED during font loading

Tags: fonts

I have an issue in google chrome console when I update my page.

`GET http://localhost:9000/OpenSans.woff net::ERR_ABORTED`

It's strange because I can see this font on my page - so it seems everything works just fine.

What should I do to fix this error in the console?

Comment: What do you mean by "update my page"? Is there any server running locally on port 9000?

Comment: yes im in process of making a webpage and i do it locally on my laptop

Comment: And everything is severed through localhost on port 9000?

Comment: Yes, everything is servered through this localhost

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you're seeing the font just fine because it is installed on your system, so whether the GET request works or not, the browser can still display the font.

i get the net::ERR_ABORTED error when requesting font families from google fonts once in a while. sometimes it is because the requested url is malformed. sometimes it just seems that google throttles the requests.

it's hard to properly answer your question without knowing more about your setup, but i would start by making sure that OpenSans.woff is actually located at the provided url (http://localhost:9000/OpenSans.woff).

hope it helps !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18882857)

Comment: why don't we first let the asker decide if it helps or not ? is this site about helping people or getting a rep ?

Comment: May I know how this helps the question? As said in the answer itself 'hard to properly answer your question without knowing more about your setup'

Comment: thanks for your comment. in my view it may help the asker inasmuch as :

- it suggests a starting point to a diagnosis process
- it provides a possible cause for the error message
- it may incite the asker to communicate more details about the situation, and more generally to keep the dialogue going

for the sake of completeness, it may also help you and me and just about any reader to better understand how answers and questions help people in general. but this last point might also be blatantly rhetorical... ;o)